# auth fails despite (i believe) correct credentials

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I signed into `manager.paypal.com` with the same credentials, but can't seem to successfully connect with curl. (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_payflow/).

```
curl -s https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -d 'ACCT=5105105105105100&
AMT=1.00&EXPDATE=1216&TENDER=C&TRXTYPE=S&
PARTNER=PayPal&
PWD=***********&
USER=********&
VENDOR=*********'
```

However I get back an error.

```
RESULT=1&RESPMSG=User authentication failed
```

The only issue I can think of is that the password includes encoded characters (an exclamation point) but I'm using Ruby to parameterize the curl shell command so it should be encoded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , sometimes its related to the special character in the password . You can try to change your password to the new one with only characters and numbers and retry again .

And one more thing you can check in your manager account under "Account Administration" that you have not specified any IP address for "Allowed IP Addresses (For API Transaction Processing)" . If you have specified any IP address there make sure your server IP initiating the API call is listed there .